# Punctuation and spaces in other common languages?

Tags: nlp, orthography, punctuation

For example, in Chinese, a full stop is `。` (U+3002) and a space is 　 (U+3000). I need to break paragraphs into sentences and I want to make it compatible with as many languages as possible. What other common languages use special punctuation or spaces?

Comment: Current techniques don't use such simple decision trees: consider how ambiguous the English "." is. The state-of-the-art sentence splitters use machine learning techniques. See https://class.coursera.org/nlp/lecture/5.

Comment: In English, the only space character is U+0020 and the only sentence terminators are `.`, `!`, and `?`. It doesn't matter how these characters are used, I just need possible spaces and possible sentence endings.

Comment: @Linksku I'm not sure that's true…

Comment: I may be mistaken, what other spaces and/or sentence terminators are there?

Comment: People who use the British convention for quoted sentences can end a sentence using `'` and `"` too, and then there are Unicode quotation marks that differentiate opening and closing quotes. Unicode has several kinds of space characters, even if you were to limit the text to English.

Comment: This is a field of its own in NLP called "sentence boundary disambiguation" (SBD) or "sentence breaking" or "sentence segmentation". There are two relevant Wikipedia articles: [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_segmentation#Sentence_segmentation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_boundary_disambiguation). As with many things in linguistics and NLP, it's not nearly as easy as you think.

Comment: Please try the sentence boundary iterators in the ICU library : http://userguide.icu-project.org/boundaryanalysis#TOC-Sentence-Boundary .  Of course, as other comments have pointed out, this can't give a perfect solution, but it might be good enough for your purposes.